# sdk_config.properties not found

Tags: java, sdk, paypal, payment

I'm trying to include paypal processing in my site. I'm using the java sdk to generate payments but whenever I attempt to authenticate I get the following error message:

> java.io.IOException: Resource 'sdk_config.properties' could not be
>   found

The code that I am executing is below:

```
String clientID = properties.getProperty("clientID");
String clientSecret = properties.getProperty("clientSecret");
return new OAuthTokenCredential(clientID, clientSecret).getAccessToken();
```

I know that the documentation says that u need maven but I'm not using maven in my project... I just used maven to build the sdk and then included the necessary jars and files in my project. I have the sdk_config.properties file located under my WEB-INF folder and I load it into the properties object prior to getting the clientID and clientSecret but whenever I try to create the OAuthTokenCredential, the code spazzes out on me. I can't find the source for the OAuthTokenCredential object to find the folly so I'm kind of stuck right here... dang it! Thx ahead of time for your help :)

Answer (score 6):

Well, after a couple of beers and alot of headache, I was able to solve my own problem. I found the [source code for the ResourceLoader object of the paypal core](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/paypal/sdk/util/ResourceLoader.java) thats being called by the OAuthTokenCredential object to load the sdk_config.properties file. I copied and pasted the ResourceLoader code into my code and ran it to see what it was doing. So basically the ResourceLoader object looks for the sdk_config.properties file on the classpath -- *and I use that term loosely because it's not actually checking the classpath of the project which is why it can't find the file* -- but it also looks for the .properties file to be in the base package of the project. So I solved the problem by moving the sdk_config.properties file to the base package of the project (meaning I put it directly under the src folder). Now it works!!!

**Silly piece of Paypal code... Y would something so critical to the processing of payments be hard coded in such a loose way. If there's a paypal developer out there listening, I recommend updating the code to allow the location of the .properties file to be passed into the OAuthTokenCredential constructor and then passing that location to the getResourceAsStream() method. Put this in the next release because I'm sure it's causing alot of people headache and alot of them probably just give up and use something else. Also, fix the searchClasspath() method... it's not searching the classpath of the project.**

Comment: And please update the java section of the Rest API Reference documentation. There's no AmountDetails object. The code requires a Details object. This stuff should just work out of the box... it doesn't. This is almost as bad as the Google Calendar API.

Answer (score 3):

If you have bundled the WAR correctly then you should say like <>.getResourceAsStream("/sdk_config.properties"); and it should work for you.

Please download the samples available in GitHub and check it out. All the PayPal Samples will work out of the box so you can also compare the code base of samples against yours.

https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-java/tree/master/rest-api-sample

Please feel free to update this thread if you still have issues.

Comment: I use getResourceAsStream() to get a handle on the .properties file to create the properties object... that's how i get the clientID and the clientSecret. But when I pass the clientID and the clientSecret to the OAuthTokenCredential constructor and try to get the access token, that's when i get the error message (java.io.IOException: Resource 'sdk_config.properties' could not be found). So although I'm able to get the .properties file in my code, the paypal core code is failing. I tried adding the .properties file to the classpath but the paypal core code is still failing to find it

Answer (score 2):

In version 0.7.1 you can use the second constructor, that has *configurationMap* as parameter. So you don't need any *sdk_config.properties*.

```
public OAuthTokenCredential(String clientID, String clientSecret,Map<String, String> configurationMap)
```

If you want to use *APIContext* without sdk_config.properties you have to call setter for set the configuration map. The map contains the same key:value pairs as in the *sdk_config.properties*.(key is case sensitive)

Example:

```
Map<String, String> configurationMap = getConfigurationMap();
String accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(clientId, clientSecret, configurationMap).getAccessToken();
APIContext apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken);
apiContext.setConfigurationMap(configurationMap);
```

Comment: Thank you! I was missing that last line (setting the properties again on the `APIContext` object), now it seems to work! Very handy when embedding the config doesn't make sense (e.g. in a multi-tenant setup).

Comment: `Map<String, String> = getConfigurationMap();` is not valid java code